# Rcpp install fails on Mac 10.8

Tags: r, rcpp

Rcpp is failing to install for me. When I run the following within the R console (R 2.15.1 on Mac 10.8):

`install.packages("Rcpp")`

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/2.15.1/R.framework/Resources/include \
       -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4/include \
       -isystem /usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Os -w -pipe - \
       march=native -Qunused-arguments -mmacosx-version-min=10.8  \
       -c exceptions.cpp -o exceptions.o

exceptions.cpp:82:14: fatal error: 'bits/exception_defines.h' file not found 
#include <bits/exception_defines.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [exceptions.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dirk's as knowledgeable as they come, but you might try posting to the r-sig-mac mailing list to see if Simon has something to suggest.

Answer (score 7):

Which version of Rcpp?  This is fixed in SVN:

> ```
> 2012-07-06  Dirk Eddelbuettel  <edd@debian.org>
>
>         * inst/include/Rcpp/config.h: In order to not attempt to include
>         exception_defines.h if on OS X (as the clang runtime may not have
>         predictable access to g+++ headers providing these), do not define
>         RCPP_HAS_DEMANGLING which is used in src/exceptions.cpp
> ```

and was discussed on the rcpp-devel list.

I tried to accomodate OS X and clang >= 3.0, but the interaction of clang and g++ is a little tricky.  Try to fetch [the file from SVN](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/Rcpp/inst/include/Rcpp/config.h?view=markup&root=rcpp) or just edit the section in it to yield

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
  // from http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?\  
  //              title=Operating_Systems#MacOS
  #ifndef __APPLE__ 
    #ifndef __MACH__
      #define RCPP_HAS_DEMANGLING
    #endif
  #endif
#endif
```

which turns this off for all OS X instances.

Comment: I encountered the same error when trying to install Rcpp 0.9.13 on a Mac. Rcppp 0.9.13 was released on 2012-06-29, i.e., before the SVN fix. So is the only option here to wait for next release of Rcpp?

Comment: Edit the file as shown in my answer, then install. Else, fetch the tarball from R-Forge, or do a SVN checkout. Else you will have to wait for 0.9.14, which should come out one of these days/weeks/months.

Comment: I'm glad to report that newly released Rcpp 0.9.14 solved the issue. Thanks, Dirk.

Comment: Oh, you're fast and you noticed the new release as it hit CRAN. Meant to mention it here too but you took care of it :)